# R Shiny: Editing DT with locked columns

Tags: r, dt, shiny-reactivity

I am trying to have a `DT` that is editable by the user but I only want certain columns to be editable. Since this isn't a feature yet in `DT`, I am trying to hack it together by having the table refresh back to the original value when edited a column that I want "locked".

Below is my code:

```
library (shiny)
library (shinydashboard)
library (DT)
library (dplyr)
library (data.table)

rm(list=ls())

###########################/ui.R/##################################

#Header----
header <- dashboardHeaderPlus()

#Left Sidebar----
sidebar <- dashboardSidebar()

#Body----
body <- dashboardBody(
  useShinyjs(),

  box(
    title = "Editable Table",
    DT::dataTableOutput("TB")
  ),
  box(
    title = "Backend Table",
    DT::dataTableOutput("Test")
  ),
  box(
    title = "Choice Selection",
    DT::dataTableOutput("Test2")
  ),
  box(
    verbatimTextOutput("text1"),
    verbatimTextOutput("text2"),
    verbatimTextOutput("text3")
  )
)



#Builds Dashboard Page----
ui <- dashboardPage(header, sidebar, body)


###########################/server.R/###############################
server <- function(input, output, session) {


  Hierarchy <- data.frame(Lvl0 = c("US","US","US","US","US"), Lvl1 = c("West","West","East","South","North"), Lvl2 = c("San Fran","Phoenix","Charlotte","Houston","Chicago"), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

  ###########

  rvs <- reactiveValues(
    data = NA, #dynamic data object
    dbdata = NA, #what's in database
    editedInfo = NA #edited cell information
  )

  observe({
    rvs$data <- Hierarchy
    rvs$dbdata <- Hierarchy
  })

  output$TB <- DT::renderDataTable({

    DT::datatable(
      rvs$data,
      rownames = FALSE,
      editable = TRUE,
      extensions = c('Buttons','Responsive'),
      options = list(
        dom = 't',
        buttons = list(list(
          extend = 'collection',
          buttons = list(list(extend='copy'),
                         list(extend='excel',
                              filename = "Site Specifics Export"),
                         list(extend='print')
          ),
          text = 'Download'
        ))
      )
    ) %>% # Style cells with max_val vector
      formatStyle(
        columns = c("Lvl0","Lvl1"),
        color = "#999999"
      )
  })

  observeEvent(input$TB_cell_edit, {
    info = input$TB_cell_edit

    i = info$row
    j = info$col + 1
    v = info$value

    #Editing only the columns picked
    if(j == 3){
      rvs$data[i, j] <<- DT::coerceValue(v, rvs$data[i, j]) #GOOD

      #Table to determine what has changed
      if (all(is.na(rvs$editedInfo))) { #GOOD
        rvs$editedInfo <- data.frame(row = i, col = j, value = v) #GOOD
      } else { #GOOD
        rvs$editedInfo <- dplyr::bind_rows(rvs$editedInfo, data.frame(row = i, col = j, value = v)) #GOOD
        rvs$editedInfo <- rvs$editedInfo[!(duplicated(rvs$editedInfo[c("row","col")], fromLast = TRUE)), ] #FOOD
      }
    } else {
      if (all(is.na(rvs$editedInfo))) {
        v <-  Hierarchy[i, j]
        rvs$data[i, j] <<- DT::coerceValue(v, rvs$data[i, j])
      } else {
        rvs$data[as.matrix(rvs$editedInfo[1:2])] <- rvs$editedInfo$value
      }
    }
  })

  output$Test <- DT::renderDataTable({
    rvs$data
  }, server = FALSE,
  rownames = FALSE,
  extensions = c('Buttons','Responsive'),
  options = list(
    dom = 't',
    buttons = list(list(
      extend = 'collection',
      buttons = list(list(extend='copy'),
                     list(extend='excel',
                          filename = "Site Specifics Export"),
                     list(extend='print')
      ),
      text = 'Download'
    ))
  )
  )

  output$Test2 <- DT::renderDataTable({
    rvs$editedInfo
  }, server = FALSE,
  rownames = FALSE,
  extensions = c('Buttons','Responsive'),
  options = list(
    dom = 't',
    buttons = list(list(
      extend = 'collection',
      buttons = list(list(extend='copy'),
                     list(extend='excel',
                          filename = "Site Specifics Export"),
                     list(extend='print')
      ),
      text = 'Download'
    ))
  )
  )

  output$text1 <- renderText({input$TB_cell_edit$row})
  output$text2 <- renderText({input$TB_cell_edit$col + 1})
  output$text3 <- renderText({input$TB_cell_edit$value})


}

#Combines Dasboard and Data together----
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Everything works as expected except within the `observeEvent` where I try to refresh the DT if they edited the wrong column:

```
      if (all(is.na(rvs$editedInfo))) {
        v <-  Hierarchy[i, j]
        rvs$data[i, j] <<- DT::coerceValue(v, rvs$data[i, j])
      } else {
        rvs$data[as.matrix(rvs$editedInfo[1:2])] <- rvs$editedInfo$value
      }
```

I can't seem to get the `DT` to coerce back to the original values (the `if`). Also, when a user has changed values in the correct column and changes something in the wrong column, it doesn't reset the original value (wrong column) while keeping the values changed (corrected column) (the `else`)

**EDIT**

I have tried the following and it coerces as expected to `"TEST"`. I have looked at the class of both `v = info$value` and `v <- Hierarchy[i,j]` and they are both character and produce the value that I expect. Cannot figure out why it won't coerce to `v <- Hierarchy[i,j]`.

```
  if (all(is.na(rvs$editedInfo))) {
    v <-  Hierarchy[i, j]
    v <- "TEST"
    rvs$data[i, j] <<- DT::coerceValue(v, rvs$data[i, j])
  }
```

Comment: [Disclaimer: author of **DT** here.] This feature will be available in **DT** in the near future and I'm still struggling to allocate time for it (there has already been a pull request on Github). Sorry!

Comment: Thanks @YihuiXie! I think it will be a great feature. If anyone knows how to do the hack now though, I'd greatly appreciate it as I'd like to publish it in my app soon.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[I have added this feature](https://github.com/rstudio/DT/commit/832714f7c928ec8f09d595a7dcd0e9ac9a860254) to the development version of **DT**.

```r
remotes::install_github('rstudio/DT')
```

You can find an example in the Table 10 of the Shiny app at https://yihui.shinyapps.io/DT-edit/.

Comment: Awesome! Unfortunately, I am working in an environment where I can only download from CRAN but I am glad you pushed it to dev! I'll wait until the new version goes to production. Great work, this package is fantastic!

Answer (score 3):

You can use the DT package directly to disable certain columns or rows as needed:

Example:

```
editable = list(target = "cell", disable = list(columns =c(0:5)))
```