# How to create a partially editable datatable in shiny?

Tags: javascript, r, datatable, shiny

I have some calculating fields in a datatable, is there a way I can make some columns editable and some fixed?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [R Shiny: Editing DT with locked columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55690492/r-shiny-editing-dt-with-locked-columns)

Answer (score 1):

If I right undestand you. You can use `contenteditable="true"` attribut for div. You can find more info [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6012852/10429440).

Answer (score 0):

Using `library(DT)` you can specify columns as such:

```
render_dt(dt1, editable = list(target = 'row', disable = list(columns = c(2, 4, 5)))
```

Learn more about `library(DT)` [here](https://rstudio.github.io/DT/) and play with some [Shiny examples here](https://yihui.shinyapps.io/DT-edit/) (Table 10 at the bottom shows the selective edit functionality).