# only specific column editable with data.table

Tags: r, shiny, dt

I use this function to modify cell in data.table. But how can i make only specific column editable?

```
library(shiny)
library(DT)
shinyApp(
  ui = fluidPage(
    DTOutput('x1')
  ),
  server = function(input, output, session) {
    x = iris
    x$Date = Sys.time() + seq_len(nrow(x))
    output$x1 = renderDT(x, selection = 'none', rownames = F, editable = T)

    proxy = dataTableProxy('x1')

    observeEvent(input$x1_cell_edit, {
      info = input$x1_cell_edit
      str(info)
      i = info$row
      j = info$col + 1  # column index offset by 1
      v = info$value
      x[i, j] <<- DT::coerceValue(v, x[i, j])
      replaceData(proxy, x, resetPaging = FALSE, rownames = FALSE)
    })
  }
)
```

Comment: hi check this https://yihui.shinyapps.io/DT-edit/   there is a column option

Comment: see here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55690492/r-shiny-editing-dt-with-locked-columns/55924091.